# unable to remove Related Contact from Financial Services Cloud Relationship Map Edit

Tags: relationships, financial-services-cloud

We have a business requirement asking why the related contacts are not removable from the list within the Relationship Map Edit page. In the screen shot the related contacts are greyed out. I'm not sure if this is a configuration or setup issue that we have control over or if its native functionality that just went unnoticed. any insight on why these are greyed out and not removable is appreciated, thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I received this from salesforce support confirming this is working as designed. i wanted to leave this here in case anyone else comes acrossed it.

"Thank you for contacting Salesforce Support, my name is Yunyang Gu and I would be happy to assist you on the issue.

This is the expected behavior, to remove the Contact-Contact relationship, you will not be able to do so through the Edit Group page, you can directly find the related contact in relationship map then 'Delete', which will then remove the relationship.

Please let me know if you have any question on this.

Best regards,
Yunyang Gu"